# Create a multiselect drop down with parent-child menu items

Tags: php, mysql, html, arrays

I am planning to create a multi select drop down or multi select check box form element in php. But with a parent child menu item relation ship.

Ex: So I have got three separate tables tbl_branch, tbl_area, tbl_region and 2 more tables for the mapping tbl_regiontoarea and tbl_areatobranch. Now I need a multi select or multi check box which looks some thing like this:

```
Branch 1
 Area 1
   Region 1
   Region 2
 Area 2
   Region 3
   Region 4
   Region 7
   Region 9
 Area 5
 Area 7
   Region 8

Branch 2 
 Area 3

Branch 3
Branch 4
Branch 5
 Area 6
   Region 10
 Area 2
```

So as you would have guessed it, **Branch** is the top most in the hierarchy and **region** is the lowermost i.e. **Branch** is the parent. I would like it to loop until it finds children for it. Once it stops finding any children it would move on to next parent item in the array.

I am very bad with arrays, and forming complex sql queries and hence was looking forward to have some starting direction on how to do this. I would really appreciate if some one could help me with the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you give this a read

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

I've set up a tree of near identical data and using the methods suggested in the above document make the issue significantly simpler especially when it comes to determining parents and siblings down to n levels.

The short version is that you assign a number on 'left' and 'right' of each node, and using that you can then select segments of the tree very efficiently.  The more long winded version is in that article, and explains it far more thoroughly than I can and includes useful MySQL code.

Here's a potential outline for your main table

```
treeTable (
    // ID field
    id INT UNSIGNED PK AI,
    // Fields for branching
    lft INT UNSIGNED,
    rgt INT UNSIGNED,
    // ID fields for the specific types
    leafType ENUM('Branch','Area','Region'),
    leafID INT UNSIGNED,
    leafName VARCHAR
)

UNIQUE INDEX (leafType,leafID)
```

If you need specific data for each type then you could create seperate tables for them but the above would let you create your tree, map out the id's and allow relationships to be stored along with a display name.

Of course the more data you can normalise between each leafType the better, ideally they are all effectively the same type of data after all as they are all a geographic subsection

Taking a sample of your data as example

```
Branch 3
Branch 4
Branch 5
 Area 6
   Region 10
 Area 2
```

you might end up with table such as

```
id  lft rgt leafType    leafID  
1   1   2   'Branch'    3   
2   3   4   'Branch'    4
3   5   12  'Branch'    5
4   6   9   'Area'      6
5   7   8   'Region'    10
6   10  11  'Area'      2
```

Queries for how to insert etc can be found in the linked article, i.e. (quoted verbatim from http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

```
LOCK TABLE nested_category WRITE;

SELECT @myLeft := lft FROM nested_category

WHERE name = '2 WAY RADIOS';

UPDATE nested_category SET rgt = rgt + 2 WHERE rgt > @myLeft;
UPDATE nested_category SET lft = lft + 2 WHERE lft > @myLeft;

INSERT INTO nested_category(name, lft, rgt) VALUES('FRS', @myLeft + 1, @myLeft + 2);

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

And then a SELECT can illustrate the tree (again verbatim from the source)

```
SELECT CONCAT( REPEAT( ' ', (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) ), node.name) AS name
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

Field/table names in the 2 above are of course unchanged, but you can update the table/field names as necessary

Following my latest comment, below is the definition for my stored procedure I use for inserting new rows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `addOptionalExtraToTree`(inParentOptionID INT,inOptionName VARCHAR(40),inLeafType VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    DECLARE myRight INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT optionalExtra_tree_right-1
    INTO myRight
    FROM optionalExtras
    WHERE optionalExtraID = inParentOptionID;

    IF myRight = 0 THEN
        SELECT COALESCE(MAX(optionalExtra_tree_right),0)
        INTO myRight
        FROM optionalExtras;
    END IF;

    UPDATE optionalExtras 
    SET optionalExtra_tree_right = optionalExtra_tree_right + 2 
    WHERE optionalExtra_tree_right > myRight;

    UPDATE optionalExtras 
    SET optionalExtra_tree_left = optionalExtra_tree_left + 2 
    WHERE optionalExtra_tree_left > myRight;

    INSERT INTO optionalExtras (
        optionalExtra_name,
        optionalExtra_leaf_type,
        optionalExtra_tree_left,
        optionalExtra_tree_right
    ) VALUES (
        inOptionName,
        inLeafType,
        myRight + 1,
        myRight + 2
    );

    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS optionalExtraID;

END;
```

This is then called using calls such as the following

```
CALL addOptionalExtraToTree(0,'New root option','Region');
CALL addOptionalExtraToTree(4,'New child option','Area');
```

Comment: I just had a read n as per my understanding, I see two problems: First, I have got data spread over multiple tables and not just one table like they have in `category` table. Secondly I have got multiple parent items like `Electronics` so would it loop thru all of them irrespective of whether or not they have children.

Comment: Well first of all you can have multiple parent nodes.  If you had one node with left-right 1:4, and a second node with left-right 5:6, then a SELECT would return them all even though the second had no children.  As a second point, you are treating all your data as being a tree which would indicate that the data is of similar type, and so to be able to do this efficiently a restructure to normalise key areas may be required, will add a suggested table layout above.

Comment: So basically are u asking me to create another table which has a super mapping of my branch/area/region. And I am still unclear as to how to insert values in this table. Can you please, if u dont mind, by actually picking from my data in the ques explain me how ur table will look like with my data?

Comment: Thanks for d elaborate example. But how will I know every time what would my left and right values be. Since I am building this feature for an application how would I keep inserting the right values for `lft` and `rgt`? do u know what I mean?

Comment: You can add the logic for insertion into a stored procedure.  I have done just that in my own tables where the stored procedure takes as input (parentID, leafType, leafName) (I have no individual leafID).  If I specify a parentID of 0 it adds it as a new root node at the end of the tree.